# How to add smtp host to send mails with this phpmail script

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to send mails using this **PHP MAILING** script but through SMTP and not through **sendmail** because my host rejects all emails as spam and I don't check my spam folder as its heavy loaded with spam emails daily.

I just want to know where to put the code which will use my SMTP logins to send mails using this php script instead of using sendmail/

I tried adding some things like

```
$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "587";
$username = "testtest@gmail.com";
$password = "testtest";
```

But these didn't worked, actually it broke the whole code itself,

**Edit: I also tried adding this, reading an answer from another answered question here, and it also broke the code itself but didn't work.**

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'johndoe@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'passwordxxx'
```

**Original Code**

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    //only shows if prevent default fails (js in index.html)
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    //only shows if prevent default fails (js in index.html)
    $errorMSG .= "E-mail is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];

}

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    //only shows if prevent default fails (js in index.html)
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


// change this to fit !
$EmailTo = "demo@domain.com";
$Subject = "New Message from MENTOR";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";


// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Somethin went wrong...";
    } else {
        echo "An error has ocurred!";
        //echo $errorMSG; Enable if you want full details of php error
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a platform for helping users solve specific, code-related questions.  As it stands, your post reads as a request for someone to do work for you.  Please edit your question so that it's related to a specific code-related problem.  For example, if you've tried implementing a solution and are running into an error of some sort, post the error here along with steps to reproduce the error.  See the following link for StackOverflow's guide to posting effective questions- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am trying to add SMTP details to the following above code, if someone can guide me where to add the smtp details then I would be very much helped by him.

Comment: I've also edited with the answers I tried from S.Overflow, and they didn't worked, maybe I'm doing something wrong here or maybe the above code don't fit in at all, as I am a newbie into php stuff so let me know how to do it correctly and where to put the SMTP details inside the php mailing page.